# Google Drive API Says "Forbidden" When Fetching File

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

For some reason I want to fetch the file from the google drive and process it on the server. From the picker I am getting the FileID and sending it to backend for download and the processing. So on downloading the file using googleapis, I am getting this error

[image]

**Prerequisites**

1. Drive API is Enabled in the Project
2. Access Token has the permission to Drive

**Permissions I have Tried**

1. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
2. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
3. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

The Code I am Using is from the GitHub

```js
const tmpDir = path.resolve(path.join(os.tmpdir(), "user-sheets"));
const file = path.join(tmpDir, Date.now().toString());

let stream = fs.createWriteStream(file);
let drive = google.drive({
    version: "v3",
    auth: "MY ACCESS TOKEN",
});

drive.files
    .get(
        {
            fileId: req.body.url,
            alt: "media",
            oauth_token: "MY ACCESS TOKEN",
        },
        {
            responseType: "stream",
        }
    )
    .then((r) => {
        r.data
            .on("end", async () => {
                console.log("ended");
                stream.close();
            })
            .on("error", function (err) {
                console.log("Error during download", err);
                res.json({
                    success: false,
                    message: "Something went wrong",
                    error: err,
                });
            })
            .pipe(stream);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.error(e.response);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer, I suppose the following points.

- `MY ACCESS TOKEN` of `auth: "MY ACCESS TOKEN",` is the valid access token for downloading the file.
- `req.body.url` of `fileId: req.body.url,` is the file ID which is not the URL.

If my guess was not correct, please tell me.

When my guess was the correct, please confirm the following modification.

#### Modification point:

- Unfortunately, `MY ACCESS TOKEN` cannot be directly used for `google.drive()` and `drive.files.get()`.

When this point is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
let drive = google.drive({
    version: "v3",
    auth: "MY ACCESS TOKEN",
});

drive.files
    .get(
        {
            fileId: req.body.url,
            alt: "media",
            oauth_token: "MY ACCESS TOKEN",
        },
        {
            responseType: "stream",
        }
    )
```

To:

```
var oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2();
oauth2Client.setCredentials({access_token: "MY ACCESS TOKEN"});
const drive = google.drive({
  version: "v3",
  auth: oauth2Client,
});
drive.files
  .get(
    {
      fileId: req.body.url,  // Please use the file ID here.
      alt: "media",
    },
    { responseType: "stream" }
  )
```

#### Note:

- In this case, the files except for Google Docs files (Google Document, Google Spreadsheet, Google Slides and so on) can be downloaded. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)

Comment: But if you would see the typings, it also accepts `string`

Comment: @tbhaxor Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.